# javascript end of loop when an item of an array is undefined

Tags: javascript

Please I am trying to display the firsts columns of a multidimensional array in JS but when the current item is undefined, the loop ends even when the following items follow the condition of the loop. this is my code.

```
for(var z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
     if(typeof(liste_des_points[z][0])!='undefined')
     alert(liste_des_points[z][0]);
 }
```

liste_des_points is actually an array built from the rows of a mysql table. N.B: I have tried to display these line independently and it works.

```
     alert(liste_des_points[0][0]);//this line display 0
     alert(liste_des_points[1][0]);//this line display 1
     alert(liste_des_points[2][0]);/*display anything because the value is      absent in the database*/
     alert(liste_des_points[3][0]);//this line display 3
```

Thanks

Comment: The loop only goes from 0 to 2.

Comment: i.e. `3 < 3 === false`

Comment: sorry i meant z<4

Comment: Please add `console.log(liste_des_points)` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(var z = 0; z <= 3; z++) {
     if(typeof(liste_des_points[z][0]) !== 'undefined') {
         alert(liste_des_points[z][0]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: he doesn't want to stop the loop, he's saying that the loop is stopping when it shouldn't.

Comment: Oh, I will edit the question to be properly worded. Sorry for that, deleting this.

Comment: Well, can't delete now.

Comment: Why can't you delete?

Comment: After comment, it says vote to delete. Anyways, I edited it.

Comment: I think you can always delete your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `liste_des_points[z]` is empty, check for `liste_des_points[z]` as well before calling `typeof()`

```
for(var z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
  if(liste_des_points[z] && typeof(liste_des_points[z][0])!='undefined')
  alert(liste_des_points[z][0]);
}
```

Comment: @Barmar We do not know what `liste_des_points[2]` is, e.g., `delete liste_des_points[2]`

Comment: He says the array is the results of a query. But I still say, if the element is deleted, `alert(liste_des_points[2][0])` would report an error, not alert an empty value.

Comment: @Barmar Where does OP state that an empty value is alerted?

Comment: He doesn't say that it gets an error when he does that alert.

Comment: @Barmar That is true as well. When tried to reproduce the missing code at OP used `delete`, which led to the Answer. If that is not the case, then OP can omit that portion of the expression.

Comment: I notice you also changed `z < 3` to `z < 4` in your answer. That's the real problem in his code, right?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, following your lead. Take no attribution for that inclusion of code. Posted an Answer based on the code tried to reproduce what OP describes `var arr = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"], ["g", "h"]];
delete arr[2]; for(var z = 0; z < 3; z++) { if(typeof(arr[z][0])!='undefined') console.log(arr[z][0])}; //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. We do not know what the value is at that index of the array. Decided to post own Answer instead of make several comments at others Answers trying to communicate the reasons for  including such a check at the expression

Comment: @Barmar "I notice you also changed z < 3 to z < 4 in your answer. That's the real problem in his code, right? " this is not the problem.